# Spring reading properties from application.properties file with wildcard

Tags: java, spring, properties

I would like to read an array of proprieties from application.properties in spring with a wildcard.

For example I have this properties:

```
file.processing.xpath.query.1=query1
file.processing.xpath.query.2=query2
```

and then I would like to get the properties in an array or in a list like this

```
 @Value("${file.processing.xpath.query.*}")
    private String[] xpathQuery;
```

is there a way to do this?

when I try to do it like this I receive an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'file.processing.xpath.query' in string value "${file.processing.xpath.query.*}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your properties like this:

```
file.processing.xpath.query=query1,query2,query3
```

And then use:

```
@Value("${file.processing.xpath.query}")
    private String[] xpathQuery;
```

Comment: any luck with testing this way?